# How to show a snackbar or toast after a user logs in

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can i show a snackbar or a toast when i user logs in `['you have successfully logged in!']`or it can be how can i show a snackbar or toast after a navigation.

Answer (score 3):

You can display it like this:

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('you have successfully logged in!'));
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Here's the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars).

Comment: after navigating to the home page?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the Flushbar Plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar
You can call it with

```
Flushbar(
    title:  "You have successfully logged in!",
    duration:  Duration(seconds: 3),)..show(context)
```